# Coinbase v2 with Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, coinbase-api

I'm trying to use the Coinbase API v2 (NOT PRO) to simply pull the contents of my wallet in to my spreadsheet. I have the following:

```
    var url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2';
    var requestPath = '/accounts';
    var api_key = '********';
    var secret_key = '********';
    // var timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString().slice(0, -3);
    var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString();
    var method = 'GET';

    var message = Utilities.base64Decode(Utilities.base64Encode(timestamp + method + requestPath));
    var decoded_secret = Utilities.base64Decode(secret_key);
    var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(message, decoded_secret));
    
    //previous attempt
    /* var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(message, decoded_secret);
    signature = signature.map(function(e) {
      var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
      return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
    }).join("");*/

    var params = {
      'method': method,
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type':        'application/json',
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN':      signature,
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY':       api_key,
        'CB-VERSION':          '2021-02-03'
      }
    };
    Logger.log(params);
    var res = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + requestPath, params);
```

Unfortunately I am getting the *invalid signature* error. I feel like I'm close. It could be that I don't have the url/request path going in to the signature correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the official document including the sample authorization process you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Creating a Coinbase signature with Apps Script is a bit tricky

As you can see from the [documentation for Coinbase API](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication), in Python the signature is built with
`signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()`.

In other words, the signature needs to be hex-encoded.

There is no 1:1 equivalent to `hexdigest()` in Apps Script, but you can build it manually.

This works for me:

```js
  var message = (timestamp + method +  requestPath + body);  
  var byteSignature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(message, secret);
  var signature = byteSignature.reduce(function(str,chr){
    chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
    return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
  },'');
```

Thereby `secret` is your credential provided by Coinbase - no need to decode it.

Comment: Thank you! Your link had the final missing piece: my request path!!
`The requestPath is the full path and query parameters of the URL, e.g.: /v2/exchange-rates?currency=USD.`
I didn't have /v2 in my path.